# python_AssertionError

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, assertion

We have a script which works for my other two colleagues, but not for me.
Issue only happens on specific files.
We have the same python version 3.8.6 and the same sql odbc drivers 17.0
I have access to the sql database.

I changed the original paths to "C:***" due to data sensitivity.

Exception has occurred: AssertionError
exception: no description

```
  File "C:***\FileToServer.py", line 1810, in bring_to_sql
    df.to_sql(self.tbl_name, conn_executemany, index=False, if_exists="replace")

  File "C:***\FileToServer.py", line 4520, in upload_to_server
    upload_success = upload_to_server_object.bring_to_sql()

  File "C:***\FileToServer.py", line 4666, in manage_upload
    upload_to_server(

  File "C:***\overrule_FileToServer_csabi.py", line 25, in <module>

    FileToServer.manage_upload(source_file_full_name="C:***EA Reports and dashboards.xlsx",
AssertionError:
```

The guy who made the code left the company and now I am try to figuring out what could be the issue.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Kind regards
Csaba

I tried changing local username uppercase to lowercase. Nothing happened.

Comment: Please add some more details and have a minimum reproductible example. One thing you can do is to go through the code and find out if an assert statement is specified explicitly. Assertion Error can be thrown if an explicit assertion is provided or it could be because of an internal function as well.